# AJAX Polling - Check for new database entry

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, polling

I'm polling my database every one second and I need it to do something only after a new entry has been submitted to the database; it can't just re-pull everything. Any help?

Comment: ? I have a mySQL that is continuously being added to and I need to make an AJAX function that checks the database periodically and only returns the ones that it hasn't seen before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can periodically check if the latest record ID matches the last ID pulled by your script, and if not, pull the new data. Example:

```
function updateView(id) {
    $.get("foo.php", { lastId: id }, function(response) {
        if(response != lastId) {

            // new entry in DB, do something special
            // and set lastId to the newly fetched ID
            lastId = id;
        }
    });
}

var i = setInterval(function() { updateView(id) }, 10000);
```

Comment: if the number of new records is more than 1, superfluous record would 'slip through' and be forgotten.